# How to perform FULL OUTER JOIN in ORACLE using '+' operator?

Tags: sql, oracle

Instead of using keywords like FULL OUTER JOIN or FULL JOIN, how can I perform full outer join using 'where' clause with the help of '+' operator?!

Comment: You would have to UNION together the results of 2 outer join queries (one for A -> B and one for B -> A)

Comment: why would you want to? Use explicit joins, it's the preferred method. Implicit joins area SQL antipattern.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Just use the `FULL OUTER JOIN` syntax (using explicit ANSI style joins over implict joins is highly recommended anyway)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't (at least directly). Oracle only supports a full outer join using SQL:1999 syntax.

You can fake it by unioning two outer joins:

```
select a.field1, b.field2
from table_a a, table_b b
where a.id = b.id(+)
union all 
select a.field1, b.field2
from table_a a, table b b
where a.id(+) = b.id
      and a.id is null
```

It's a lot more readable using the SQL:1999 syntax:

```
select a.field1, b.field2
from table_a a full outer join table_b b
on a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example you can run in oracle to see the results for yourself as well.

```
with 
a as 
   (select 'A' tbl, level id from dual connect by level < 1000),
b as 
   (select 'B' tbl, level + 500 id from dual connect by level < 1000)
select a.tbl, a.id, b.tbl, b.id from a, b where a.id = b.id(+)
union all
select a.tbl, a.id, b.tbl, b.id from a, b where a.id(+) = b.id and a.id is null
```

Is the same as:

```
with 
a as 
   (select 'A' tbl, level id from dual connect by level < 1000),
b as 
   (select 'B' tbl, level + 500 id from dual connect by level < 1000)
select a.tbl, a.id, b.tbl, b.id from a full outer join b on a.id = b.id
```