# Oracle: "ORA-00918 column ambiguously defined" even after using fully qulaified names

Tags: oracle, join, view, oracle10g, ambiguous

I am trying to join two views like this:

```
Select CH.ID 
From V_CHARGE CH 
full outer join V_TEMPCH VT 
on CH.ID = VT.ID_CHARGE
```

And I am getting "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined" error, although i am using the aliases before the column names.
I've been stuck at this for an hour. Please help

**UPDATE**

Well, the views used in the join had multiple joins within themselves. And the joins were taking one after the other like this:

```
Select *
From tblA A
cross join tblB B
left outer join tblC C
on C.id = b.ID
```

What solved the problem was separating the joins using parenthesis like this:

```
Select *
From (Select *
      From tblA A
      cross join tblB B
     ) D
left outer join tblC C
on C.id = D.id
```

Still didn't understand why there was a problem using the first syntax as there were no conflicting columns in the tables being joined.
Thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: Please show the table definitions.

Comment: Can you make `SELECT * from V_CHARGE` and `SELECT * from V_TEMPCH`?

Comment: Yes I can, the views compile successfully

Comment: If the `v_` prefix indicates these are both views, is there any chance that the error you're getting could be coming from one of the view definitions rather than from the `full outer join` query?

Comment: @JustinCave yes, both are views. But the views are working fine, i have compiled them again and again. I can join them with other tables as well. I think the error has got something to do with the column name ID, because it might also be a keyword, as it turns blue in TOAD :)

Comment: The DB is on another network and I can't copy paste the view definitions, I'll try and type it here.

Comment: what happens with inner join or left join?

Comment: @FlorinGhita I have just tried that. inner join as well as left, right joins work fine.

Comment: Tried them all to no avail. Is there something that I can do at my end manually? I mean if there is a problem with the optimization of the queries used to create views, will that solve the problem if I have a look at them again?

Comment: It was a try. Sometimes the optimizer rewrite a query in a manner that is not runnable :) . Let's delete these comments about enabling backward optimizer. Maybe there is something really illegal in your code.

Comment: Ok, I am going through the scripts of views once again. Will update if anything works. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? I can see from the tags that it's 10g. There is a bug in My Oracle Support for ORA-918 with full outer join in 10.2.0.3 and 10.2.0.4: Bug 6319169 - ORA-918 on full outer join (Doc ID 6319169.8)

Answer (score 2):

For this bug, you also have that workaround:

```
alter session set "_column_elimination_off"=true;
```

(as seen https://community.oracle.com/thread/2431395?tstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your tagging is correct, be aware that full outer join was buggy in Oracle 10 - especially with views - [as discussed here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1064722?tstart=0). You could try using the WITH syntax they noted, and if it is some oddity with the optimizer rewrite as some commenters have noted, you might be able to sidestep it with some aliasing and sub-querying:

```
Select CH.ch_ID 
From (SELECT "ID" AS ch_id from V_CHARGE) V_CH 
   full outer join (select id_charge as vt_id from V_TEMPCH) V_T 
on v_CH.ch_ID = V_T.vt_ID
```

If both the WITH syntax and that still gives an error, then I would dig deeper into the views

The other thing to note is that in 10G full outer join using the old oracle syntax DID work. It's ugly. Its not ANSI. And I have worked hard to get some old-school developers to stop using it - but it wasn't buggy.

[See here for the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500020/how-to-perform-full-outer-join-in-oracle-using-operator) if you aren't familiar with the old (+) implementation